# Shift in 2 GIS KML Layers when using Custom Icon

Tags: icons, gis, kml, layer, shift

I am using Leaflet to display map as background to load 3 kml layers(Point & Line) on it, when it uploading in default icon everything is fine but when I am taking custom icon points layer is shifting from line layer.

Comment: What does your KML look like?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `<hotspot>` for your custom icon correctly.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?csw=1#hotspot)

> `<hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction">`
>   Specifies the position within the Icon that is "anchored" to the  specified in the Placemark. The x and y values can be specified in three different ways: as pixels ("pixels"), as fractions of the icon ("fraction"), or as inset pixels ("insetPixels"), which is an offset in pixels from the upper right corner of the icon. The x and y positions can be specified in different ways—for example, x can be in pixels and y can be a fraction. The origin of the coordinate system is in the lower left corner of the icon.
>
> - x - Either the number of pixels, a fractional component of the icon, or a pixel inset indicating the x component of a point on the icon.
> - y - Either the number of pixels, a fractional component of the icon, or a pixel inset indicating the y component of a point on the icon.
> - xunits - Units in which the x value is specified. A value of fraction indicates the x value is a fraction of the icon. A value of pixels indicates the x value in pixels. A value of insetPixels indicates the indent from the right edge of the icon.
> - yunits - Units in which the y value is specified. A value of fraction indicates the y value is a fraction of the icon. A value of pixels indicates the y value in pixels. A value of insetPixels indicates the indent from the top edge of the icon.